# Questions from a newbie

Tags: wordpress, background, header, html

Here is my home page: http://www.danmihaila.net/
I am trying to do a few things and I am not sure how because I am new not only to WordPress and web design but also to CSS.
There are three things I want to do right now and I can't really figure out how:

First of all, I use Clear Retina theme.

1. I know I can change the background color but for some reason when I do this, the background behind the header remains unchanged.
2. I don't see how I can make my main URL, danmihaila.net load my Home page. Should I set the Home page differently?
3. How can I add a sub menu to a certain page? What I want is when you hoover your mouse over one specific page, I want it to show a few other sub pages. I assume I have to create some sort of a sub menu but I am not sure.

   Solution to point no.3: I figured the parent thing in the pages menu. It seems to do what I want it to do..

But I am getting more and more confused because while trying to figure out the Home page thing, I am starting to not understand what pages are and what a menu is...

Sorry if my questions are trivial but I am really really new to this. I am building this site just to host my  Computer Graphics portfolio.
Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here are a few suggestions: First, when you have a few questions, please consider creating a StackOverflow question for each one. Second, please don't link to a site then ask for help on changing it. If the link breaks, the question is useless to future users. For graphical problems, you could take a screenshot and post the screenshot in the question.

Comment: The title of your question should describe what you're asking about, i.e. be more descriptive than "question from someone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the background on your `#branding` in your stylesheet. (`Appearence > Editor`)
2. Goto `Settings > Reading`. On `Front page displays:` set it to `A static page` and select your home page.. looks like home-3
3. for a submenu, goto `Appearence > Menus`. you can add pages from the left panel to your navigation. If you drag the navigation items, you can re-arrange or nest them. Nested items will be your sub navigation.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to get everything right except the background... You said to change #branding and I went and found it in the Editor... But I am not really sure what to change from this:   #branding {
 background: url("images/header-bg.jpg"); 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #f3f3f3;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #f3f3f3;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #f3f3f3;
}

Comment: if you want to change the background image do this: `background: url("[NEW URL]")` if you want to remove the background image completely delete this: `background: url("images/header-bg.jpg")`... and be careful centering all your text that is a no no in web...

Comment: also, if you want to change the footer bg as well you will have to find and edit `#colophon` in your stylesheet

Comment: Ok.. I figured which background I had to change and it looks kinda ok but now, since I changed it to black (almost) I need to change the website title and all the writing.. I managed to do this with the text.. however I can't figure where to change the page title and the site title.. I tried in pages and it won't let me change the title.. only the text in the content..

Comment: i see your progress.. if you want to remove or change color of that horizontal line you can do this: remove: delete `border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #f3f3f3; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #f3f3f3; box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #f3f3f3;` from branding... change color: enter different hex value for `#f3f3f3` like `#333333`.. for the site title and tagline: goto `Settings > General` and change it there.. also adjust your timezone settings..

Comment: ahh you mean change the color... if you are in Chrome you can right click any element and click inspect element.. once the developer tools come up, look in the right panel, it will show you what classes are applied to which element and what line of the css it is in.. in general, you can change line 65 of the stylesheet to: `body, input, textarea { color: #cccccc; ....`

Comment: Just saw your last post.. brb

Comment: wow man! Thank you so much.. That developer tools thing.. IS FREAKING AWESOMe.. jesus.. what a noob I am.. Ahm ok.. I took enough from your time! Thank you so much for your patience. And I will upvote your replys.. Sorry.. First time user.. didn't see that thingy. One last question: If I will have other issues.. and if I really can't find a solution.. Can I come back here and ask?

Comment: for more coloring, find these: `.entry-title, .entry-title a`, `#site-description`, `#site-title a`, `#site-generator`, and `#site-generator .copyright a`

Comment: Nvm this :) I figured it out

Comment: Nevermind.. I'm stupid.. Done it :)

Comment: i left you a comment on your site with my contact info if you need more help.